# Calling a Main function from a userControl

Tags: c#, function

I need to call a function from my Main from a userControl. 
I tried to put my function in static which doesn't work, because in this function I access controls of the Main form so I have an error :

> an object reference is required for the property the method or the non-static field

Here is my code:
Function to call:

```
        public void ShowSP(bool isClick, Projet projet)
    {

        if (isClick)
        {
            clearProjectPanel();
            foreach (var sousProjet in projet.sousProjects)
            {
                int x = 0, y = 0;
                UserControl_sousProjet userControl = new UserControl_sousProjet(sousProjet);
                userControl.Location = new Point(x, y);
                panel_projects.Controls.Add(userControl);
                y += userControl.Height;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            refreshProject();
        }
    }
```

Where I want to call him :

```
        private void label_projetName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!isClick)
            isClick = true;
        else
            isClick = false;

        // Affiche / Enlève les sous projet d'un projet         
        Main.ShowSP(isClick, projet);
    }
```

Thank you if you have a solution

EDIT :

And I don't know if it's a mistake, but when I say "Main", I mean a form!

Comment: Events is the way to go... Raise Event inside the control, and handle the event in main form.

Comment: Excuse me, but I didn't understand anything

Comment: Check the example below. Once you do it once, it will make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the different forms to communicate you need to declare an event in the child `Form` so that the parent can get the data.

Official docs on the Event usage, can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=netframework-4.8)

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnClick;
```

Then in your parent control

```
public void ShowSP(object sender, ThresholdReachedEventArgs e) {
      // Access from e.isClick and e.projet
}

// Assign this whenever the child control is available.
childControl.OnClick += ShowSP;
```

And again in the child control

```
private void label_projetName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!isClick)
        isClick = true;
    else
        isClick = false;

    // Affiche / Enlève les sous projet d'un projet  
    ThresholdReachedEventArgs args = new ThresholdReachedEventArgs();
    args.isClick= isClick;
    args.projet = projet;       
    OnClick(null, args);
}
```

Comment: I have to put where the **childControl.OnClick += ShowSP;** ?

Comment: Just updated. Child control is the reference to your control of which I don't know the name.

Comment: and the **public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnClick;**

Comment: This should go in your custom control, as a public member.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the method in your parent form public, and also create a property of main form type in your UserControl:

```
public Main MainForm { get; set;}  // add this to your user control (imagining that Main is Form class)
```

Then you can access it in the UserControl like:

```
MainForm.PulicMethodYouWantToCall();
```

Comment: I still have the mistake: **an object reference is required for the property the method or the non-static field** :/

Comment: This is not a good approach... Defeats the Objected Oriented approach..